# How to stop Python Selenium Firefox from login in to website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am trying to automate Firefox browser using python Selenium. The browser keeps logging me into my company website. I am not sure how to stop it from logging me in. I have tried

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = False
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

and

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

But that didn't work it still logged me in. Is this a certificate issue? I think Selenium web driver is doing SSO. I was wondering how I can turn that of in Selenium webdriver?

The end goal is to navigate to the login page without logging in.

Comment: sounds like domain level login... try running from a machine/account that is not logged into the domain.  (or maybe a VM)  Are you sure the site allows a login from outside the domain?  (intranet?)

Comment: When I open the browser normally it doesn't log me in. The internet doesn't automatically log me in. Only when I use Selenium webdriver.

Comment: You must be setting the driver to use a specific profile that is already logged in?   By default it will use a fresh/temporary profile.